# ics file calendar assignment to the correct calender

Tags: icalendar

Is there a way when user open the ics file the event can auto assign to the correct calendar.

My client is report having trouble as on the iCalender when click on the ics file it give you the option to select which calendar you would like to assign to. But outlook just auto create a new calendar for you. is there a way you can define which calender goes into?

So hard for me cause i don't have PC to test out.

is it **X-WR-CALNAME:** the one to modify to match his calender name?
[image]

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:test
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dedb6dbe42977eb4c5718454e104c5cb
LOCATION:
DTSTAMP:20131119T101138Z
DTSTART:20131119T101100Z
DTEND:20131120T101100Z
SUMMARY:Flashcube
DESCRIPTION: test
URL;VALUE=URI:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed the non standard compliant calendar property defined by microsoft. see the page [Property: X-WR-CALNAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157721%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

however given that your example only has one event, impotant to note the microsoft standard says:

> This property MUST be omitted if the iCalendar represents a single appointment or meeting.